# SQL Find latest record meeting certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I feel like this should be easy but I'm having a hard time getting it. We have a table with UnitID, DateTimeStamp, and UnitStatus. Like so:

[image]

I'm trying to find the latest record (based on DateTimeStamp) for each unit if their last UnitStatus was LO. So in the screenshot I've taken of a sample database I would be looking to have it return:

```
E02 2017-02-06 03:00:00 LO .....
E04 2017-02-06 06:00:00 LO
```

(It would not return E03 because E03 had a UnitStatus of AV after their UnitStatus of LO)

I've tried doing max(cdts) with different where statements. Joining a query to another query that used max(cdts). But whatever I try I never get the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. **Update** After reading updated question, I've updated my answer

```
SELECT tbl1.*
FROM defaulttable as tbl1
RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT UnitStatus FROM defaulttable
    WHERE UnitStatus = 'LO'
) as tbl2
ON tbl1.UnitStatus != tbl2.UnitStatus
WHERE tbl1 != 'LO'
ORDER BY tbl1.DateTimeStamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with desc keyword

```
SELECT * from table
WHERE UnitStatus = 'LO'
ORDER BY DateTimeStamp desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using window function row_number to get the latest record for each UnitID

```
Select *
From (
  Select
    t.*,
    Row_number() over (partition by UnitID order by datetimestamp desc) rn
  From your_table t
  Where UnitStatus = 'LO'
) t where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
    select *,
    Row_number() over (partition by UnitID order by DateTimeStamp desc) as rn
    from theTable 
) 
select * 
from cte 
where rn = 1
and UnitStatus = 'LO'
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` retrieves the UnitIDs, the `OUTER APPLY`ed subselect retrieves the unitIDs with most recent status 'LO':

```
with t as (select distinct unitid from SO42060982)
select t.*, sub.*
from t
outer apply 
   (select top 1 * from SO42060982 sub 
    where t.UnitID = sub.UnitID order by DateTimeStamp desc) sub
where sub.UnitStatus = 'LO'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ROW_NUMBER() function to get the latest record for each UnitId as specified above. As the second step filter the records based on their rowindex and Status, Then i think you should be able to achieve what you were looking for

Step 1

```
SELECT U.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UNITID ORDER BY DATETIMESTAMP DESC) SNO
INTO #UNITSTEMP
FROM UNITS U
```

Step 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #UNITSTEMP WHERE SNO = 1 AND UNITSTATUS = 'LO'
```

After running the above queries your result will be as shown in the screenshot below
[image]